# Creating a button that will make a request to a URL with a random query string

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a small project where I'm tasked to create a button that will generate a random string, and then append it to a URL as a query string using another button.  I’ve completed the random string generator, but I’m having difficulties creating a button to attach it on a URL. I was wondering what would be the best method to accomplish this.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h1>HTML PROJECT</h1>

    <script lauguage="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function randomString() {
        var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        var string_length = 10;
        var randomstring = '';
        for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
            var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
        }
        document.getElementById("randomfield").value = randomstring;
    }
    </script>
    <fieldset>
    <h1>Generate String!</h1>
    <form name="randform" >
    <input type="button" value="Generate" onClick="randomString();">
    <input type="text" name="randomfield" id="randomfield" value="" disabled>
    </form>
    </fieldset>
    <script>
    var url = file:///I:/completed!.htm? + text; 
    </script>
    <fieldset>    
    <h1>Now press the button below to place the string on the URL!</h1>
    <form action= file:///I:/completed!.htm" + randomString()' >
      <button type="submit">String Me!</button>
    </form>
    </fieldset>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<h1>HTML PROJECT</h1>
<fieldset>
    <h1>Generate String!</h1>
    <form name="randform" >
        <input type="button" value="Generate" id = "generate"/>
        <input type="text" name="randomfield" id="randomfield" value="" disabled ></input>
    </form>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>    
    <h1>Now press the button below to place the string on the URL!</h1>
    <form name="myform">
      <button type="submit">String Me!</button>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

**JS**

```
var url;
var btn = document.getElementById('generate');
generate.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 10;
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    document.getElementById("randomfield").value = randomstring;
    url = 'file:///I:/completed!.htm?'+randomstring;
    document.myform.action = url;
});
document.myform.addEventListener('submit', function(){
    alert(this.action);
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mtbXW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location or a get ajax request, depending on your needs.

Answer (score -2):

```
$(".searchButton").click(function(){
var textVal = $("input:text[name=InputBox]").val();

value = "t=" + textVal;
location.href = "yourURL" + value;
});
```

Comment: The code the OP has so far doesn’t have jQuery, nor any element with a class of `searchButton`.

Comment: It is just an example .. searchButton is just a placeholder. Assuming he knows JQuery, if he does not he will make a point. I am just giving an answer if that does not work for him, he can always say that.

Comment: all true, but as it stands, it’s not a clear and helpful answer to the question asked.

Comment: Will make sure not to repeat that in future :\